# Linux: is it possible to share code between processes?

Tags: c, linux, memory, ipc, mmap

I wonder if it's possible for a linux process to call code located in the memory of another process?

Let's say we have a function f() in process A and we want process B to call it. What I thought about is using mmap with MAP_SHARED and PROT_EXEC flags to map the memory containing the function code and pass the pointer to B, assuming, that f() will not call any other function from A binary. Will it ever work? If yes, then how do I determine the size of f() in memory?

=== EDIT ===

I know, that shared libraries will do exactly that, but I wonder if it's possible to dynamically share code between processes.

Comment: Not directly. Either use dynamic libraries or [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: That's exactly what libraries are for. Depending on what you are going to accomplish, [IPC](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html) might do too.

Comment: Is the code you want to share generated by a compiler, or generated by your program?

Comment: How can you be sure that `f` is not calling any other function? (The compiler do insert some calls even when your source code don't have any apparent call).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that, but the first process must have first created the shared memory via `mmap` and either a memory-mapped file, or a shared area created with `shm_open`.

If you are sharing compiled code then that's what *shared* libraries were created *for*. You can link against them in the ordinary way and the sharing will happen automatically, or you can load them manually using `dlopen` (e.g. for a plugin).

---

Update:

As the code has been generated by a compiler then you will have *relocations* to worry about. The compiler does not produce code that will Just Work anywhere. It expects that the `.data` section is in a certain place, and that the `.bss` section has been zeroed. The GOT will need to be populated. Any static constructors will have to be called.

In short, what you want is probably `dlopen`. This system allows you to open a shared library like it was a file, and then extract function pointers by name. Each program that `dlopen`s the library will share the code sections, thus saving memory, but each will have its own copy of the data section, so they do not interfere with each other.

Beware that you need to compile your library code with `-fPIC` or else you won't get any code sharing either (actually, the linkers and dynamic loaders for many architectures probably don't support libraries that aren't PIC anyway).

Comment: I actually have never tried running code from mmaped memory.. does it really work? How about permissions?

Comment: @KBart: Is should work as long as the PROT_EXEC permission is set. Not all architectures will support that flag, of course, but in most of those cases you can't *stop* it working.

Comment: That's nice. Could you give a little example maybe? I believe that's exactly what this question is about anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The standard approach is to put the code of `f()` in a shared library `libfoo.so`. Then you could either link to that library (e.g. by building program *A* with `gcc -Wall a.c -lfoo -o a.bin`), or load it dynamically (e.g. in program *B*) using [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) then retrieving the address of `f` using `dlsym`.

When you compile a shared library you want to :

- compile each source file `foo1.c` with `gcc -Wall -fPIC -c foo1.c -o foo1.pic.o` into [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), and likewise for `foo2.c` into `foo2.pic.o`
- link all of them into `libfoo.so` with `gcc -Wall -shared foo*.pic.o -o libfoo.so` ; notice that you can link additional shared libraries into `lbfoo.so` (e.g. by appending `-lm` to the linking command)

See also the [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

You could play insane tricks by  `mmap`-ing some other `/proc/1234/mem` but that is not reasonable at all. Use shared libraries.

PS. you can `dlopen` a big lot (hundreds of thousands) of shared objects `lib*.so`files; you may want to `dlclose`them (but practically you don't have to).

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to do so, but that's exactly what shared libraries are for.

Also, beware that you need to check that the address of the shared memory is the same for both processes, otherwise any references that are "absolute" (that is, a pointer to something in the shared code). And like with shared libaries, the bitness of the code will have to be the same, and as with all shared memory, you need to make sure that you don't "mess up" for the other process if you modify any of the shared memory.

Determining the size of a function ranges from "hard" to "nearly impossible", depending on the actual code generated, and the level of information you have available. Debug symbols will have the size of a function, but beware that I have seen compilers generate code where two functions share the same "return" piece of code (that is, the compiler generates a jump to another function that has the same bit of code to return the result, because it saves a few bytes of code, and there was already going to be a jump anyway [e.g. there is a if/else that the compiler has to jump around]).

Answer (score 0):

- *not directly*
- *that's what shared libraries are for*
- *relocations*

**Oh no!  Anyways...**

Here's the insane, unreasonable, not-good, purely academic demonstration of this capability.  It was fun for me, I hope it's fun for you.

#### Overview

Program `A` will use `shm_open` to create a shared memory object, and `mmap` to map it to its memory space.  Then it it will copy some code from a function defined in `A` to the shared memory.  Then program `B` will open up the shared memory, execute the function, and just for kicks, make a very simple modification to the code.  Then `A` will execute the code to demonstrate the change took effect.

Again, this is no recommendation for how to solve a problem, it's an academic demonstration.

```
// A.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int foo(int y) {
  int x = 14;
  return x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const size_t mem_size = 0x1000;
  // create shared memory objects
  int shared_fd = shm_open("foobar2", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
  ftruncate(shared_fd, mem_size);
  void *shared_mem =
      mmap(NULL, mem_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_SHARED, shared_fd, 0);
  // copy function to shared memory
  const size_t fn_size = 24;
  memcpy(shared_mem, &foo, fn_size);
  // wait
  getc(stdin);
  // execute the shared function
  int(*shared_foo)(int) = shared_mem;
  printf("shared_foo(3) = %d\n", shared_foo(3));
  // clean up
  shm_unlink("foobar2");
}
```

Note the use of `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC` in the call to `mmap`.  This program is compiled with

```
gcc A.c -lrt -o A
```

The constant `fn_size` was determined by looking at the output of `objdump -dj .text A`

```
...
000000000000088a <foo>:
 88a:   55                      push   %rbp
 88b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 88e:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
 891:   c7 45 fc 0e 00 00 00    movl   $0xe,-0x4(%rbp)
 898:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
 89b:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
 89e:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
 8a0:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 8a1:   c3                      retq   
...
```

I think that's `24` bytes, I dunno.  I guess I could put anything larger than that and it would do the same thing.  Anything shorter and I'll probably get an exception from the processor.  Also, note that the value of `x` from `foo` (`14`, that's (apparently) `0e 00 00 00` in LE) is located at `foo + 10`.  This will be the constant `x_offset` in program `B`.

```
// B.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const int x_offset = 10;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // create shared memory objects
  int shared_fd = shm_open("foobar2", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
  void *shared_mem = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shared_fd, 0);
  int (*shared_foo)(int) = shared_mem;
  int z = shared_foo(13);
  printf("result: %d\n", z);
  int *x_p = (int*)((char*)shared_mem + x_offset);
  *x_p = 100;
  shm_unlink("foobar");
}
```

**Anyways** first I run `A`, then I run `B`.  The output of `B` is:

```
result: 27
```

Then I go back to `A` and push `enter`, then I get:

```
shared_foo(3) = 103
```

Good enough for me.

#### /dev/shm/foobar2

To completely eliminate the mystique of all this, after running `A` you can do something like

```
xxd /dev/shm/foobar2 | vim -
```

Then, edit that constant `0e 00 00 00` just like before, then save the file with the 'ol

```
:w !xxd -r > /dev/shm/foobar2
```

and push `enter` in `A` and see similar results as above.